# Invalid octal digit error

Tags: ruby, api, octal

Invalid octal digit error in Ruby, how do I by pass that? I have a number, `0962833`, which I need to send to an API but I can't send it since I get this invalid octal digit error.

I need a work around for that without turning that number into a string, the zero can't be removed, it's a must.

Comment: A leading `0` means the value will be interpreted as octal representation.  Why can't you remove it?

Comment: Are you sure that `0962833` really is a number rather than a string, `'0962833'`, that just happens to be made up of digits? Zip codes, for example, often look like numbers but they're not, they're strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Octal numbers use the digits 0 to 7. Maybe the error could be the digit 9, and digit 8 in your number.
If you want to pass the number '962833', try converting it first to a correct octal number with an online converter. Then add the leading '0' and pass it to your function.

Comment: There's no need for an online converter: `"0962833".to_i(10).to_s(8)
=> "3530421"` :-)

Comment: You guys are right, it wasn't a number issue since I change it to a string, the problem was with my curl command.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`0962833` is an octal number because of the leading zero, so you can't have digits higher than 7. If you need the leading zero, why can't you turn it into a string? Leading zeroes have no [mathematical significance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures), so why should there be a way to represent them in a numerical type?