# eval function: converting datetime to a string in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, datetime

I'm trying to convert a standard datetime object into a string.

I've tried:

```
datetime_object.to_s
```

and

```
"#{datetime_object}"
```

but I get an error in both cases - "Invalid octal digit".

Any idea what is happening here?

edit, I'm trying to do this within the eval function in order to convert a string to a hash. I think that's where the issue is... but not sure why it's happening.

```
eval("{:date => {:id => " + @unit.id.to_s + ", :start_datetime => " + @start_datetime.to_s + ", :end_datetime => " + @end_datetime.to_s + "}}" )
```

DateTime format I'm using is: 2014-08-20 13:00:00

Comment: `Time.now.to_s` OR `DateTime.now.to_s` is this object you are trying to convert? what is in you `datetime_object` ?

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177320/invalid-octal-digit-error

Comment: It's a DateTime object, e.g. 2014-08-20 05:00:00

Comment: yep i saw that. that is about dealing with a number with leading zeros without turning into a string. doesn't solve my issue

Comment: Can you provide sample code to reproduce error?

Comment: look at http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html to see what Ruby thinks is a valid DateTime Object. You may have to covert your object before you can call `to_s` on it.

Comment: Let me get this straight.... You've got `start_datetime`, and `end_datetime`, which, although you've called them datetime, you actually want to use as strings? Why not just make those values be datetime, instead of a string? What are you hoping to achieve by turning a Datetime into a string? You know that a hash will happily hold a Datetime value?

Comment: Why the use of eval? The output of `to_s` may or may not be valid ruby - it's just a human readable string

Comment: I agree with Mr. Cheung, constructing the Hash from a literal (`{key: value, key2:value2}`) might easier to read. and needs no eval. To be more clear on what is happening give us the output of `@start_datetime.class.name`, please.

Comment: Mr. Cheung, Semionmant, you're absolutely right. Much better to do as a literal. That's allowed me to fix up my issue. Thanks so much for the help.